# java.time.format.DateTimeParseException in java 17 but not in java 11

Tags: java, datetime-format, java-11, java-17, datetimeformatter

I am migrating a service from jdk 11 to jdk 17. But I kept getting errors in **java 17**:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.time.format.DateTimeParseException: Text '09/18/2018 10:31:40 PM' could not be parsed at index 0
at java.base/java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter.parseResolved0(DateTimeFormatter.java:2052)
at java.base/java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter.parse(DateTimeFormatter.java:1954)
at java.base/java.time.ZonedDateTime.parse(ZonedDateTime.java:600)
at Main.convertToEpoch(Main.java:15)
at Main.getOrderTime(Main.java:54)
at Main.lambda$dateTest$0(Main.java:60)
at java.base/java.util.Arrays$ArrayList.forEach(Arrays.java:4204)
at Main.dateTest(Main.java:60)
at Main.main(Main.java:71)
```

However I don't get this error in **java 11**. Following is the sample code:

```
public class Main {
public static Long convertToEpoch(String dateTime, String pattern) {
    System.out.println(ZoneId.systemDefault());
    DateTimeFormatter dateTimeFormatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern(pattern).withZone(ZoneId.systemDefault());
    return ZonedDateTime.parse(dateTime, dateTimeFormatter).toInstant().toEpochMilli();
}

private static Long getOrderTime(String orderSavedTime) {
    try {
        return convertToEpoch(orderSavedTime, "yyyy-M-d'T'H:m:sXXX");
    } catch (DateTimeParseException e) {
        System.out.println("unable to parse date in yyyy-M-d'T'H:m:sXXX  trying next format ");
    }
    try {
        //one space less
        return convertToEpoch(orderSavedTime, "MMM d yyyy h:m:s a");
    } catch (DateTimeParseException e) {
        System.out.println("unable to parse date in MMM d yyyy h:m:s a trying next format ");
    }

    try {
        return convertToEpoch(orderSavedTime, "M/d/yy h:m:s a");
    } catch (DateTimeParseException e) {
        System.out.println("unable to parse date in M/d/yy h:m:s a trying next format ");
    }
    try {
        return convertToEpoch(orderSavedTime, "M/d/yyyy h:m:s a");
    } catch (DateTimeParseException e) {
        System.out.println("unable to parse date in M/d/yyyy h:m:s a trying next format ");
    }

    try {
        return convertToEpoch(orderSavedTime, "yyyy-M-d H:m:s");
    } catch (DateTimeParseException e) {
        System.out.println("unable to parse date in yyyy-M-d H:m:s trying next format ");
    }

    try {
        return convertToEpoch(orderSavedTime, "MMM  d yyyy h:m:s:SSSa");
    } catch (DateTimeParseException e) {
        System.out.println("unable to parse date in yyyy-M-d H:m:s trying next format ");
    }

    return convertToEpoch(orderSavedTime, "MMM d yyyy h:m:s:SSSa");
}

public static void dateTest() {
    List<String> formats = Arrays.asList("09/18/2018 10:31:40 PM", "10/18/2018 3:39:24 AM", "9/18/2018 10:31:40 PM", "9/18/2018 3:39:24 PM", "9/18/2018 2:43:08 PM",
            "9/18/2018 5:09:05 PM", "09/09/2018 06:32:29 PM", "09/09/18 06:32:29 PM", "08/09/18 06:02:20 PM", "8/9/18 6:2:2 PM", "Nov  1 2018 12:00:00:000AM");
    formats.forEach(v -> System.out.println(v + " -> " + new Date(getOrderTime(v))));
    System.out.println("new form");
    formats = Arrays.asList("Sep 22 2014 10:33:55:555AM", "Sep 02 2014 2:3:5:555AM", "Sep 2 2014 2:3:05 AM", "Oct 12 2004 02:3:50 PM", "2018-09-08T00:00:00+05:30",
            "Nov  1 2018 12:00:00:000AM");
    formats.forEach(v -> System.out.println(
            v + " -> " + ZonedDateTime.ofInstant(Instant.ofEpochMilli(getOrderTime(v)), ZoneId.systemDefault()).format(DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("MMM d yyyy h:m:s:SSSa"))));
    formats.forEach(v -> System.out.println(v + " -> " + ZonedDateTime.ofInstant(Instant.ofEpochMilli(getOrderTime(v)), ZoneId.systemDefault())));

}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    dateTest();
    }
}
```

Same sample code in java11 runs properly:
*Partial output (for first element)*

```
Asia/Kolkata
unable to parse date in yyyy-M-d'T'H:m:sXXX  trying next format 
Asia/Kolkata
unable to parse date in MMM d yyyy h:m:s a trying next format 
Asia/Kolkata
unable to parse date in M/d/yy h:m:s a trying next format 
Asia/Kolkata
09/18/2018 10:31:40 PM -> Tue Sep 18 22:31:40 IST 2018
```

It might be related to **AM/PM** markers and case sensitivity, but the original code is *legacy* and I don't want to make a lot of changes.

Comment: The way you try all those formats, you’ll always see the exception of the last attempt, which fails at position zero already. If you were checking the exception of the match attempt you expected to succeed, you could see at which position in the input string it failed.

Comment: @Holger Yes I did, and it fails if the date in List `formats` have uppercase **AM/PM** and succeeds at LowerCase **am/pm**. I want to know why this is happening as it was running perfectly in Java11. Also knowing the reason might help me prevent any issues rising in the java src code logic.

Comment: Can not reproduce. The `DateTimeFormatter` even produces uppercase AM/PM when formatting a datetime. And the example program doesn’t fail with JDK 17 when using US locale.

Comment: Okay, @Holger could it be possible that this issue persists as my system default is ASIA/Kolkata (en_IN) as locale. If yes then without switching my locale to US or English, How do I fix it? I am new to java and spring, it will be great if you could tell me why is this happening or from where I can know about it?

Answer (score 1):

> ...could it be possible that this issue persists as my system default
> is ASIA/Kolkata (en_IN) as locale. If yes then without switching my
> locale to US or English, How do I fix it?

I highly recommend that you always specify a `Locale` with a `DateTimeFormatter` object which is always `Locale`-sensitive. However, if you do not want to use it in this case, you can use create a case-insensitive `DateTimeFormatter`.

**Demo**

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        DateTimeFormatter dtf = new DateTimeFormatterBuilder()
                .parseCaseInsensitive() // For case-insensitive (e.g. am, Am, AM) parsing
                .appendPattern("d MMM uuuu h:m a")
                .toFormatter();

        // Test
        Stream.of(
                "24 Oct 2016 7:31 pm",
                "24 Oct 2016 7:31 PM"
        ).forEach(s -> System.out.println(LocalDateTime.parse(s, dtf)));
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
2016-10-24T19:31
2016-10-24T19:31
```

[<kbd>ONLINE DEMO</kbd>](https://ideone.com/SPHQGX)

Learn more about the modern Date-Time API from **[Trail: Date Time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/index.html)**.